# Laravel 4 Intervention package not intalling

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm trying to install the Intervention Image package for Laravel but it's not working.

In my composer.json file I have this:

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.1.*",
    "intervention/image": "1.*"
},
```

Then from the command line in my project directory I have:

```
php composer.phar install
```

I get this:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.jso
n. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
Generating optimized class loader
```

I've try running update and then tried installing it again but nothing seem to work.

Any help would be much appreciated,

Thanks in advance, Scott

Answer (score 0):

You might have broken a composer lock file. Remove your vendor folder and composer.lock file:

```
rm -rf vendor
rm composer.lock
```

If you are on Windows, use windows explorer to delete the vendor folder and the composer.lock file.

And then install it all again:

```
composer install
```

Comment: 'rm' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Comment: Any ideas? I still don't know what's going on

Comment: Ah! Yeah, you're on windows, right? Just delete the vendor folder manually and the file. And then run composer install.

Comment: Getting this error: [RuntimeException]
Failed to clone git@github.com:nikic/PHP-Parser.git, git was not found, che
ck that it is installed and in your PATH env.

Comment: Looks like composer is having trouble to download packages in your computer. Sometimes it gets odd this way, just wait a while and try again.

Comment: I had to reinstall git on my computer. Now it's working.